# Evaluate the integral $I=\iint\limits_S fdS\ \ \text{where}\ f=1-x^2-y^2-z^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

> Evaluate the following integral:
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &I=\iint\limits_S fdS\ \ \text{where}\ f=1-x^2-y^2-z^2,\\
> &S \text{ is a part of the plane $x+y+z=1$ that lies inside of the sphere } x^2+y^2+z^2=1
> \end{aligned}
> $$

I tried to approach this problem using sphere parametrization:
$$
dS=R^2\sin\theta\ d\theta,\ \ I=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}d\varphi\int\limits_0^\pi(1-R^2)R^2\sin\theta\ d\theta
$$
Then I understood that I had to express $R$ in terms of $\varphi$ and $\theta$, and the last integral is actually not that simple. Maybe there is a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of the plane $x+y+z=1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$  is a circle of radius $r=\sqrt{\frac23}$. And, from symmetry

$$I=\iint\limits_S (1-x^2-y^2-z^2)dS= \iint\limits_S (1-3z^2)dS
=\frac{2\pi}3 -3 \iint\limits_S z^2dS\tag1
$$

For convenience of integration, rotate the coordinates to have the $z$-axis aligned with the normal direction of the plane $x+y+z=1$, i.e. $(1,1,1)$, which simplifies the equation of the plane $w=\frac1{\sqrt3}$ and

$$z= \frac1{\sqrt3}w- \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}u
$$
Then, the integral becomes

$$ \iint_S z^2dS
 =\iint_{u^2+v^2\le \frac23}
(\frac1{\sqrt3} \frac1{\sqrt3}- \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}u)^2 dudv=\frac{4\pi}{27}
$$

Plug into (1) to obtain the integral

$$I= \frac{2\pi}9$$

Answer (score 0):

If you use sphere parametrization, $\theta$ is fixed. In this case, $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $dS = R^2 sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) dR d\varphi$.

Comment: But why is $\theta$ fixed?

Comment: If you change to a rotated coordinate system $(u,v,w)$ where the equation of the plane becomes $w=1/\sqrt{3}$, *then* $\theta$ becomes easier to handle (but it's not fixed, and the upper bound is not $\pi/4$).